# Having trouble with decimal points in SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, to-char

I have a function that I am using to insert values in to my DB.  Here is the relevant part of my insert function:

```
BEGIN
....
INSERT INTO TABLE1   (AMOUNT)
VALUES (pAmount);
```

......

So this statement works fine, but if pAmount = 531.42, it inserts 531 to my DB.  So it does not take into consideration anything after the decimal point.   Fyi, I have also tried:

```
VALUES (to_char(pAmount, '99,999.99'));
```

And this also cancels the decimal.  Is there a quick fix to this?

Comment: What is the definition of the column AMOUNT on TABLE1?

Comment: What is the data type of your pAmount field?

Comment: What are your NLS settings? What's the AMOUNT column's data type?

Comment: @Dante617  oh, sorry. I knew I forgot something.  I just have it as a VARCHAR2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the datatype of the column?  If it is NUMBER(10,0) for example then that means 10 digits max, 0 decimal places.  You would want NUMBER(10,2) to allows for 2 decimal places for example.

Comment: This was the problem.  Thanks so much.  Will accept when it allows

Answer (score 1):

What is the data type of AMOUNT? I'll bet it is an integer or numeric that rounds to integer.